# android APK build failed "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'"

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'. > More than one
>   file was found with OS independent path
>   'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'

This happens when trying to build APK from this file https://github.com/node-on-mobile/node-on-android

Answer (score 8):

Try adding this inside your build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
}
```

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue compiling the project, the solution I found is in two steps:

- Rename `jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so` to `jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libc++node_shared.so`
- Change line `401` of `src/main/include/node/common.gypi` into

  ```
   'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY': 'libc++node',
  ```

There is also a repository [issue](https://github.com/node-on-mobile/node-on-android/issues/15) where I'm going to suggest this solution.